# How to add multiple strings in conditonal 'if' using 'or'?

Tags: python-3.x, input

I have a solution to use `weight_type.upper()` but I am still learning and I want to know why [weight_type == 'L' or 'l':] is not giving me the right answer.

```
weight = input("What is your weight? ")
weight_type = input("Is it in (L)bs or (K)g? ")
if weight_type == 'L' or 'l':
    print(f"Output weight in (K)g is {int(float(weight))*0.453592}")
elif weight_type == "K" or 'k':
    print(f"Output weight in (L)bs is {int(float(weight))*2.20462}")
else:
    print("Unsupported weight type")
```

Result:

```
What is your weight? 70
Is it in (L)bs or (K)g? k
Output weight in (K)g is 31.75144

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You should try to tell us what you are doing/trying. You say you are trying to use `weight.upper()`, but what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I apologize for incomplete information. My motive is to take in the user input without the limitations of capitalizing the input on the users end, i.e. whether user type "small" L or "capital" L, it should give the appropriate results.

Comment: This is what you did wrong. You basically have to do this for the if: 
```if weight_type == "L" or weight_type == "l":```. You have to include it for the second after the or. You typed:
```if weight_type == "L" or "l":```. There is a difference. 
Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: no problem^^ glad to help